# Is There a Tool to Select Files to Download From an Org in VSCode?

Tags: mavensmate, vs-code

Is there a way/extension in VSCode for selecting files to pull down from an org that doesn't require hand-editing the package.xml manifest file as one would in Workbench? This is one of the features that I miss the most from MavensMate.

Answer (score 4):

The "Org Browser" feature, which includes listing and retrieving metadata from an org but not currently building a `package.xml`, is part of the [July 2019 updates](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/07/salesforce-ides-july-2019-updates.html).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Just had to restart and preferences -> Settings -> Salesforce Feature Previews -> Org Browser: Enabled. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As is often the case, conceptualizing the question helped me to find the answer: it looks like the [Salesforce Package.xml Generator Extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator&ssr=false) extension is fairly close to what I need.

update: looks like the new org browswer feature suggested by [David Reed](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/46017/david-reed) is an even better solution ([how to configure](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/user-guide/org-browser)).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you an always build a package in Setup (Setup > Packaging > Package Manager), then download it using your favorite tool (DX, Ant, VS Code, etc all support packages in some way). This lets you maintain the package inside Salesforce directly, without hand-editing a file. Building a package in Setup also means that all developers working on the project can use whatever IDE they prefer without having to pass around XML files or even use a repository.

Also, the new DX file structure does not require a package.xml, you can wildcard-retrieve most components, and the few remaining ones you can't are also pretty easy to get without raw XML editing. Building the package in XML has always been the lowest-common denominator when all else fails.